# Discrete probability distribution where (max - min) $\not=$ average

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with $N$ possible values and some distribution. What are some *well-known* distributions for $X$ such that

> $\mathbb{P}(x_{max}) + \mathbb{P}(x_{min}) \not= \frac{2}{N}$,

where $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ are the values of $X$ with the smallest and largest probability, respectively?

As a counterexample, this equality clearly holds for the uniform distribution, since $$\mathbb{P}(x_{min}) = \mathbb{P}(x_{max}).$$

Comment: Have you tried *any* other probability distributions?

Comment: Yes. One possibility is the Poisson distribution. But the more examples I can accumulate, the better.

Comment: The equation isn't well-defined for the Poisson distribution since $N$ isn't finite and the distribution doesn't have a maximum value.

Comment: Of course. I assumed $N$ was finite and therefore had a maximum value. Your answer below is actually a much nicer solution to what I'm seeking. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a discrete random variable which takes $N$ possible values, assume that 
$$\mathbb{P}(x_{max}) + \mathbb{P}(x_{min}) = \frac{2}{N}$$

Then the probability associated with the rest of the distribution is $$\mathbb{P}(\{x: x\text{ is neither max nor min}\})= \frac{N-2}{N}$$

So literally any distribution which does not satisfy the equality, i.e. such that $$\mathbb{P}(\{x: x\text{ is neither max nor min}\})\not= \frac{N-2}{N}$$

will also fail to satisfy the original equality in which you were interested. (This is just the contrapositive statement.)

**Examples:**

Almost all binomial distributions (i.e. any such that $p^N \not= \frac{1}{N}$)

All (or almost all) hypergeometric distributions

Any distribution with infinite support (possible number of values), e.g. any geometric distribution, any Poisson distribution, any negative binomial distribution.

Comment: This is much better than trying to find a (non-exhaustive) list of distributions that fit my criteria. Thanks for the insight!